# Find minimal length/width to enclose 3 identical pens each of 900 square feet?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, area

The question in my Calculus book states, "A farmer wishes to fence off three identical adjoining pens each of 900 square feet. What are x and  y so that the least amount of fence is required?"

I know $Area = (length)(width)$, and given the information $xy=900$ with $900(3)=Total Area$:

```
 |---|---|---|
 |   |   |   |
 |   |   |   |  One full vertical side is called [y].
 |___|___|___|  One single horizontal section is called [x].
```

So,  I have $4y+6x=2700sqft$.
Solving for $y$ I find $y=675-(3/2)x$.
If I set $y=0$ and solve for $x$ I find:

```
 0=1350-3x 
 0=450-x 
 x=450
```

Now what do I do to finish solving the problem?

Comment: Where is the second equation from? Describe the fence in terms of x and y, as a function. Than use derivatives to minimize.

Comment: The second  equation is what I figured out given the information (no idea if actually relevant). One Vertical section of the adjoined pens is called $[y]$, and one horizontal section of the adjoined pens is called $[x]$, thus with each of the 3 pens having an area of 900sqft, a total area equation would be $4y+6x=2700sqft$. Does that help?  I'm not following what you are saying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You are mistaken to say that $4y+6x=2700$. The left hand side, $4y+6x$, is the length of the fence, which you are to minimize but for which you do not have a fixed value. The right hand side, $2700$, is the combined area, not the fence length.

Use your equation $xy=900$ to get an expression of $y$ in terms of $x$:
$$y=\frac{900}x$$

Now substitute that into your formula for the length of fence, and we get
$$L=4\cdot\frac{900}x+6x$$

Now find the value of $x$ that minimizes the value of $L$, with the usual calculus techniques.

Comment: Rory, I'm not following what you are saying in that last part? (Though I now see my mistake in correlating length of fence with total area, thanks for pointing that out).

Comment: The usual calculus technique for finding minimal values is to take the derivative, solve for 0, and then confirm it is a minimum (not maximum) value of the function.

Comment: One correction - it is 2y and not 4y.

Comment: @Moti: What do you mean? The only $4y$ I have represents the *four* vertical lengths of fence in the diagram in the OP.

Comment: My mistake. I missed, I assume, the fact that 3 separate enclosures are required.